# Show window on Marker's click in Angular Google Maps

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-maps

I am using http://angular-google-maps.org/api in order to work with a Google map.
So far I am able to show the markers but somehow I can't get to show the windows on click.

```
<markers models="markers" coords="'last_known_location'" icon="'icon'" click="'onClicked'">

    <windows show="'showWindow'" closeClick="'closeClick'" ng-cloak>
                <p ng-non-bindable style="width:200px">{angular{ options.title }angular}</p>
                <p ng-non-bindable>{angular{ latitude | number:4 }angular}, {angular{ longitude | number:4 }angular}!</p>
    </windows>

</markers>
```

As you can see, it uses the `showWindow` property to show the window

I add this to each marker by doing

```
angular.forEach($scope.markers,function(marker){

        marker.closeClick = function() {
          marker.showWindow = false;
          $scope.$apply();
        };

        marker.onClicked = function(){
          alert(marker.id);
          onMarkerClicked(marker.id);
        };

 });
```

The alert shows up on click, and

```
var onMarkerClicked = function(marker){

  marker.showWindow = true;
  $scope.$apply();

}
```

The property is also changed, but the window doesn't show up.

Any ideas? thanks

Comment: I have noticed that I don't specify most of the required parameters in the ``windows`` directive, going to fulfil them all and see what happens

Comment: Ever figure this out?  I am having this exact issue.

Answer (score 1):

Your code actually works fine here...

The problem with it is that you're passing marker.id to onMarkerClicked, not the marker itself...

Also, I didn't need  $scope.$apply() to make it work...

Now I'm trying to figure out how to access the model obj inside the windows tag...